# Is there a way to get time zone abbreviations in browser Javascript?

Tags: javascript, time, browser, timezone

I can get the tz name with `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` - e.g in my browser's case, `America/Los_Angeles`. Is there a way to instead get the abbreviation for the time zone (as of asking this question, PDT)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can format just the time zone name, in short form, and then pull it out of the formatted parts, like this:

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {timeZoneName: 'short'}).formatToParts().find(p => p.type === 'timeZoneName').value
```

Keep in mind a few things though:

- The language matters.  `'en'` here is English.  You could pass `undefined` to use the end-user's language, but not all languages have time zone abbreviations defined.
- The specific date and time matters.  The `formatToParts` accepts a `Date` object, but when left absent (or `undefined`) it uses the *current* date and time.
- Not all time zone abbreviations are well defined.
- Not all time zone abbreviations are used consistently.
- Not all time zone abbreviations are unique.
- Not all time zones have abbreviations.

Thus, I highly recommend avoiding time zone abbreviations if you can.